# Нужен ли в данном случае `FOREIGN KEY`?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Всем привет. У меня есть 3 таблицы без внешних ключей. (Значения упустил).

```
super_heroes
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sh_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| power    | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enemy_id | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
initials
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sh_id   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| initial | varchar(5) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
enemies
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| enemy_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city     | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Я делаю запрос на вывод данных из полей каждой таблицы:

```
SELECT sh.name, sh.power, i.initial, e.name FROM super_heroes sh 
NATURAL JOIN initials i 
INNER JOIN enemies e 
ON e.enemy_id = sh.sh_id;
```

Эту таблицу получаю на выходе:

```
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| name  | power | initial | name  |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| Man   | Hands | M       | Slug1 |
| Women | Boobs | W       | Slug2 |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Но вот в чем вопрос: 
Когда смотрел урок (по которому и делал эти таблицы) там использовался `FOREIGN KEY` который применялся к `enemy_id` в таблице `super_heroes` и ссылался на `enemy_id` из таблицы `enemies`, но я не применял `FOREIGN KEY` и у меня все получилось. Так, нужен ли `FOREIGN KEY` в данном примере? Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, почему связываете ID супергероя и ID врага? Не должно ли быть ON e.enemy_id = sh.enemy_id;?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FOREIGN KEY` — это вид *ограничений* (constriants), способ организации ссылочной целостности. Он нужен, чтобы исключить (в вашем случае) возможность добавления в таблицу `super_heroes` записи с врагом (`super_heroes.enemy_id`), которого не существует в таблице `enemies`. Или чтобы при удалении или изменении в таблице `enemies` в таблице `super_heroes` не осталось героя без врага (для этого существуют разные политики `ON DELETE` и `ON UPDATE [CASCADE | RESTRICT | SET NULL | NO ACTION]`).

Answer (score 4):

Нужен для обеспечения целостности данных. Упрощенно, если будет внешний ключ - то когда в super_heroes есть герой с ID 100 вы не сможете удалить этого врага из Enemies. Сейчас это сделать можно, и в Вашем запросе супергерой просто выпадет из выборки).